# jsRender how to do a boolean comparison

Tags: json, templates, boolean, jsrender

I'm trying to do something very simple - test a boolean value from JSON in a jsRender template.

**JSON DATA:**

{
...
"CanAdd": false,
"CanDelete": false,
"CanEdit": true,
...
}

**Template:**

{{if CanEdit === true}}
  DO SOMETHING
{{/if}}

The generated output does not display "DO SOMETHING".  CanEdit's value in JSON data is true.  I've tried CanEdit === "true", CanEdit == true, CanEdit == "true" and nothing works.

What am I mising?

**EDIT**
Here's my full template:

```
            <section class="ManagePageContentSection">
            <h2>{{:PageTitle}} Page</h2>
            {{for SectionContentList}}
                <section class="PageSectionContent">
                    <h3>
                        {{:SectionName}} Section

                        {{if CanEdit === true}}
                            <span id="editPageSectionButton" class="editButton" title="Edit {{:SectionName}}">edit</span>
                        {{/if}}

                        {{if CanDelete === true}}
                            <span id="deletePageSectionButton" class="deleteButton" title="Delete {{:SectionName}}">delete</span>
                        {{/if}}
                    </h3>
                    {{if PageContentList.length > 0}}
                        <table class="PageContentTable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Order</th>
                                    <th>Title</th>
                                    <th>Subtitle</th>
                                    <th>Summary</th>
                                    <th>Actions</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {{for PageContentList}}
                                <tr id="{{:ContentId}}">
                                    <td>{{:Ordinal}}</td>
                                    <td>{{:Title}}</td>
                                    <td>{{:SubTitle}}</td>
                                    <td>{{:Summary}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{if CanEdit}}
                                            <span id="editPageSectionButton" class="editButton" title="Edit {{:Title}}">edit</span>
                                        {{/if}}
                                        {{if CanDelete}}
                                            <span id="deletePageSectionButton" class="deleteButton" title="Delete {{:Title}}">delete</span>
                                        {{/if}}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                {{/for}}
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    {{/if}}
                </section>
            {{/for}}
        </section>
```

**JSON**

```
{

"AsOfDate": "/Date(1342800529826-0500)/",
"FullPageUrl": "/home/index",
"NavigationId": 7,
"NavigationName": "Home",
"PageContainerName": "ContentRenderedContainer",
"PageId": 2,
"PageName": "Home",
"PageTitle": "Home - Home",
"SectionContentList": [
    { … },
    { … }
],
"AddContentUrl": "",
"AddSectionUrl": "/PageSection/New/2",
"AdminTemplateName": "PageSectionContentTemplate",
"CanAdd": false,
"CanDelete": false,
"CanEdit": true,
"DeletSectioneUrl": "/PageSection/Delete",
"DeleteContentUrl": "",
"EditContentUrl": "",
"EditSectionUrl": "/PageSection/Edit"
```

}

The template is rendering, except for logic around CanEdit, CandDelete.

I'm about to give up on doing templating and go back to rendering HTML on the server.  Perhaps what I'm doing is too complicated.  Maybe templating should just be used for read-only data.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: As far as I can tell, from my own experience and demos I've seen, you are doing it correctly. I'm assuming what you are showing is just a part of the actual template, does the rest of the template render? Do you get any errors? Sometimes something as simple as a stray space can cause the template to break, so it might be helpful to post the full, actual, JSON object and template.

Comment: Works for me. You can also write {{if canEdit}} ... {{/if}} - which will test for 'truey'. See also [sample](http://localhost:60288/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/04_if-else-tag.html) and [sample 2](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/10_comparison-tests.html).
You can post a simplified version of your code to jsfiddle and link to it from here, if it is not working for you.

Comment: You are trying to access "CanEdit" and "CanDelete" from within `{{for SectionContentList}}` and `{{for PageContentList}}` but they aren't objects within either `SectionContentList` or `PageContentList`. @BorisMoore would know better than I, but I believe you need to make use of `#parent.data` to access those objects

Answer (score 0):

```
{{if variable}} do something {{/if}}
```

Will show "do something" if "variable" evaluates to true.

It will not show if "variable" is null or evaluates to false.

Use `!variable` to check for false.